# iOS blink flashlight with UISwitch, UISlider and NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, flashlight, blink

I'm making a flashlight app and i'm in problem

how to blink the flashlight with uiswitch, uislder and nstimer.

i found something on web but I can't understand it.

I already done how to turn on the flashlight(LED)
but I can't find how to blink it.
Also, I can't use NSTimer well.

```
self.blinkTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(timerUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I found this code in Stack Overflow but `@selector(timerUpdate)` and `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3` is problem.

my plans are

uislider's value --> scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(uislder's value)

uiswitch --> start blinking the flashlight.

```
- (void)toggleFlashlight
{

}

- (IBAction)blink:(UISwitch *)sender {

}


- (IBAction)blinkspeed:(UISlider *)sender {
    int progress = lroundf(sender.value);
    self.blinksliderlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dms", progress];
}
```

Sadly, I don't know.. how to insert the code there...
Please help :(

Comment: Not to dim your fire...but you do realize that a very capable flashlight is front and center in control center, right?

Comment: Yes, I know that.. but it is not my personal app. So I have to make that. and as you know, the control center can't blink. :(